# Examples of ODEs that are toy models for complicated phenomena in PDEs

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let me elaborate on what I mean by the title of this question.

In studying (specifically non-linear) PDEs, one finds that each term in the equations contributes a certain amount to the behavior of the solution and the resulting behavior of the said solution depends on the tension between these effects. Such effects are for example non-linearity, transport, diffusion, dispersion, and dissipation. I am interested in example where these phenomena are manifested in simpler ODEs, and these examples would then be considered toy models.

One example would be a tension between linear dissipation (the first term) and non-linear growth (the second term) manifested in this ODE:
$$
\dot{y}(t)=-y+y^2, y(0)=y_0\neq 0, 1.
$$
Let $y_0>0$. This is well manifested in the solution, which takes the form
$$y(t)=\left(1+e^t\left(\frac{1-y_0}{y_0}\right)\right)^{-1}$$
is globally defined for $t\ge 0$ if $y_0<1$ (the linear term dominates), and in fact $y(t)\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$. However if $y_0>1$, then the solution blows up at $t=-\log(1-1/y_0)$, originating from the fact that the non-linear term is dominating.

I am looking for similar examples where the solution to an ODE qualitatively represents the tension between effects seen in more complicated PDEs.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the [Lorentz ODE system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system) is a simplified model of [Rayleigh-Benard convection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93B%C3%A9nard_convection).

Answer (score 3):

Consider the *sine-Gordon* partial differential equation
$$\tag{1}
\partial_t^2 u -\partial_x^2u +\sin (u)=0, \quad t\in\mathbb R, x\in\mathbb R. $$
The solutions $u=u(t)$ that are constant in space satisfy the ordinary differential equation of the *mathematical pendulum*; letting $y(t)=u(t)$,
$$\tag{2}
\ddot y + \sin(y)=0.$$

I am very far from being an expert of these models, but [this Wolfram Mathematica notebook](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SystemOfPendulumsARealizationOfTheSineGordonModel/) nicely demonstrates how (1) can actually be seen as an infinite system of coupled pendulums (2). The constant-in-space situation that we just described corresponds to all pendulums swinging at unison.

Thus, the mathematical pendulum can be seen as a "building block" for the sine-Gordon equation. I submit that this does count as a "toy model". Even without going too deep into the theory, you can check in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine-Gordon_equation#1-soliton_solutions) that solutions are often identified up to equivalence mod $2\pi$. The variable $u$ ($\varphi$ in Wikipedia) is often referred to as a *twist*, that is, an angle. The pendulum identification gives at least an intuition for these mental models.

Answer (score 2):

The [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) allows the transformation of hyperbolic PDEs into ODEs.
Consequently, influences of diffusion vs. transport are excluded, but you can study the effect of nonlinear terms.

A classic example for this related to [Burgers' Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers%27_equation#Inviscid_Burgers%27_equation) (which itself is a model-problem for more complex PDEs) which reads

$$ \partial_t u + \frac12 \partial_x \big(u^2\big) = \partial_t u + u \partial_x u=  0. \tag{1} \label{1}$$

Considering the [Riemann Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_problem)

$$ u(t = t_0, x) = u_0(x) = \begin{cases} u_l & x < 0 \\ u_r & x > 0 \end{cases} \tag{2} \label{2} $$
it is well-known that the solution $u(t,x) = u\big(t, x(t) \big)$ of \eqref{1} stays constant along the characteristic curves
$$ x(t) = u_0(x_0)t + x_0. \tag{3} \label{3}$$

Define now $v := \partial_x u$ and differentiate \eqref{1} with respect to $x$ (assuming existence of partial derivatives):
\begin{align}
0&=\partial_t u_x + u_x u_x + u u_{xx} \tag{4} \\
\Leftrightarrow 0&=\partial_t v + v^2 + u v_x \tag{5} \label{5}
\end{align}
Along characteristics \eqref{3} $u$ and thus $v$ are only functions of time $t$ and thus
$$v_x\big(t, x(t) \big) = v_x\big(t, u_0(x_0)t + x_0 \big) = 0. \tag{6}$$
Consequently, \eqref{5} simplifies to
$$v'(t) = - v^2(t) \tag{7} $$
with solution
$$v(t) = \frac{1}{t+c} \tag{8}$$
which can, depending on the initial condition, blow up in finite time.
For instance, for $v(t_0 = 0) = v_0 = -1$, the solution is given by
$$v(t) = \frac{1}{t-1}. \tag{9}$$

As a consequence, the spatial derivative $\partial_x u(t) = v(t)$ can blow up in finite time, even if the initial spatial derivative is small.
This is related to the fact that Burgers equation develops a discontinuity (i.e., infinite spatial derivatives) at time $ t_\text{Blow up} $ if there exists $x$ such that $u_0'(x) < 0$.
This time can be computed as
$$t_\text{Blow up} = \frac{-1}{\min_x u_0'(x) }. \tag{10}$$